# Blackberry Development in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, blackberry

I am looking into developing a small app to run on a blackberry which will send a few commands to a windows app. I installed the plugin for Visual Studio development IDE. Where can I find information on blackberry development in visual studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this Article in CodeProject: [BlackBerry Java Application Development Using Visual Studio](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mobile/BlackBerryAndVisualStudio.aspx). Also, in BlackBerry Website there is a [good videos for Developing BB apps with Visual Studio](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/resources/videolibrary.jsp#tab_tab_visualstudio).

Comment: I am kinda a screwed here. I have VS 2008 so no J#